# Representation theory: terminology

Tags: representation-theory, harmonic-analysis, terminology

I am learning about representation theory. One of the things which continually trips me up is the (abuse of?) notation $V$ for a representation. Normally, one writes $(\rho, V)$ for a representation, where $\rho$ is a linear map from the group $G$ to $GL(V)$, ie invertible linear maps on $V$.
However, sometimes people just say that $V$ is a representation.
I then don't know what the corresponding $\rho$ is.

The following example illustrates this, taken from *Harmonic Analysis on Finite Groups* by Ceccherini-Silberstein, Scarabotti and Tolli. (Overall I really like this book!)
Section 4.6, *The Canonical Decomposition of $L(X)$ via Spherical Functions*, starts as follows (slightly paraphrased).

> Let $(G, K)$ be a Gelfand pair. Let $N+1$ be the number of orbits of $K$ on $X := G/K$.
>   We know that $L(X)$ decomposes into $N+1$ distinct irreducible subrepresentations and that there exist distinct spherical functions, say $\phi_0 \equiv 1$, $\phi_1$, ..., $\phi_N$.
>
> Denote by $V_n := \langle \lambda(g) \phi_n \mid g \in G \rangle$ (where $\lambda$ is the left regular representation) the subspace of $L(X)$ spanned by the $G$-translates of $\phi_n$, for $n = 0, 1, ..., N$.
>
> ...
>
> The representation $V_n$ is called the spherical representation associated with the spherical function $\phi_n$. In particular, $V_0$ is the trivial representation.

I do not understand fully how $V_n$ is a representation. There must be some underlying linear map. If it isn't stated, is it just assumed to be $\lambda$, the left regular representation?

Comment: This is a bit basic for MO. You are right, here the $G$-action comes from $\lambda$. Visibly $V_n$ is invariant since $\lambda(h)\lambda(g) = \lambda(hg)$ for $h \in G$. Indeed, it is common to identify a representation with the underlying vector space. This makes more sense from the point of view of modules: given a representation $\rho : G \rightarrow \mathrm{GL}(V)$, where $V$ is a complex vector space, we can give $V$ the structure of a $\mathbb{C}G$-module by $g \cdot v = \rho(g)v$. Conversely, as a $\mathbb{C}G$-module, $V$ determines $\rho$.

Comment: Thank you, @MarkWildon, for your quick response. I agree that in this case it's quite clear what the representation should be, as $V_n$ is explicitly defined. Are you saying that it is always the case that $V$ determines $\rho$? I only studied modules *very briefly* six years ago, so cannot really comment. Further, there has been no mention in this book (or any of the other books/papers which I've read) on this matter. *In particular*, when unstated---"let $V$ be a representation of $G$"---it's not always implicitly left regular, ie $(V, \lambda)$"?

Comment: To clarify: (1) as a $\mathbb{C}G$-module, $V$ determines $\rho$; (2) as a vector space, $V$ does not determine $\rho$, but the intended action should be clear from the context. (3) The action is not usually the left-regular action (even on a coset space): for instance the left-regular action of $G$ on $\mathbb{C}(G/K)$ (or equivalently functions $G/K \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$) always has a trivial subrepresentation, so is not irreducible, unless $K = G$. By the way, is your reference correct? My copy, published 2014, only has three chapters.

Comment: (2) So when a paragraph starts "let $V$ be a representation of $G$", should I just read that as "let $(\rho, V)$ be a representation of $G$, and we shall use the [standard] shorthand $g \cdot v := \rho(g) v$, and hence not need to speak of $\rho$ explicitly"? // Regarding the book, this is the one to which I am referring: https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/harmonic-analysis-on-finite-groups/093299951BEB7852105CCFFCA7DA5CD9. It's a 2008 book. Are you thinking of "Representation Theory and Harmonic Analysis of Wreath Products of Finite Groups"? (same authors, three chapters).

Comment: Yes and yes (my mistake).

Comment: @YCor I returned the title to its original, because the question really isn't about spherical harmonics representations. This was just one particular example where it's come up. This (abuse of) notation comes up lots of times. Often I am unable to work out what it is intending to mean (thank you, Mark, for helping). The spherical case was just an example -- one in which I did know what it meant.

Comment: @SamT I removed capitals for homogeneity, although I won't do it again if you revert it. It would help too if you find a slightly more specific title (RT is hugely broad)

Answer (score 0):

This is a relatively standard abuse of notation, which appears in other areas as well. Some examples:

1. "Let $X$ be a topological space" rather than "Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space"
2. "Let $V$ be a vector space" rather than "Let $(V, 0, +, -, \cdot)$ be a vector space".
3. "Let $R$ be a ring" rather than "Let $(R, 0, +, -, \cdot)$ be a ring"

(I welcome additional examples, as well as cases where it can be misleading)

Comment: Here's somewhere it can be confusing: often one wants to consider the endomorphisms $\mathrm{End}(X)$ of an object $X$ as a ring (or an algebra); usually in this case the product is implicitly understood to be composition; but sometimes it is very reasonable to consider another product (e.g., the convolution product for endomorphisms of a Hopf algebra); in this latter case, it may be that the identity element of the algebra is not the identity map.

Comment: The other answer is extremely misleading, in my personal view. (Not enough rep to comment, though, or downvote.) If one simply says "let $V$ be a representation" then sure, this is shorthand for "let $(V, \rho)$ be a representation but we're suppressing the notation dependence on $\rho$". This is even more natural than their ring/vs examples as one can just write $g \cdot v$ for $\rho(g) v$, whereas one would write $+$ in the vector space/ring. However this is not what the OP is asking. A particular vector space is defined and then it says "$V_n$ is a rep". There must be some linear map $\rho$